# Generating SAS to access Azure storage

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to write a Bash script that would take backup of an Azure App service and save the backup into a container in Azure storage.

To do so, I need a SAS to access the storage and to generate one I would use the following command:

```
az storage blob generate-sas -c containername --account-name storage-account-name -n blob-name
```

The problem here is, I also need to provide the blob name for the above command to work, but I would like my backup to be stored directly in the container.

But if I am using Powershell and follow the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-powershell-backup) it doesn't require a blob storage name to create a SAS.

So I was wondering if there's a way to generate SAS using Azure-CLI that is valid on the container level and not on the blob level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try `az storage container generate-sas`.

```
az storage container generate-sas --name <container-name> --expiry <sas-expiry> --permissions <permissions> --account-name <account-name> --account-key <account-key>
```

To see all options with this command, please use:

```
az storage container generate-sas --help
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gaurav. Yes, you could generate SAS that is valid on the container level. You also could use the following commands to generate it. It works on bash shell.

```
groupname=<>
accountname=<>
containername=<>
##generate connection-string
StorageAccountConnectionString=`az storage account show-connection-string --name $accountname --resource-group $groupname --output tsv`
##generate sas
sas=`az storage container generate-sas --connection-string $StorageAccountConnectionString -n $containername --permissions rl --expiry 'Y-m-dTH:M:SZ' --output tsv`

#usage example

groupname=shui
accountname=shui
containername=shui
##generate connection-string
StorageAccountConnectionString=`az storage account show-connection-string --name $accountname --resource-group $groupname --output tsv`
##generate sas
sas=`az storage container generate-sas --connection-string $StorageAccountConnectionString -n $containername --permissions rl --expiry '2018-06-30' --output tsv`
echo $sas
se=2018-06-30&sp=rl&sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=GTdFdruu2DxzSoIKCb0K7YQpBPaJdHSaXLUPSOzTcZ4%3E
```

You also could use Azure CLI 2.0 to get storage key.

```
#usage example
az storage account keys list -n shuihdi -g shui4 --output tsv|head -n 1|awk '{print $3}'
5NQdibPibJrxQ3StybPb1kMsAL8NVdL3GT3KWcodWL96vhBNz5fYRKuXmYWkHxPxvxGnmJTOAY2rizgnJa4qmQ==
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I actually upvoted your answer.